# WordPress: Using same subpages slugs for multiple parent pages

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, url-rewriting

Let'say i want to create some product pages on wordpress.

Eg:

example.com/product1
example.com/product2
example.com/product3

Now how can i add exact subpages to all of the pages?

Eg:

example.com/product1/intro
example.com/product2/intro

example.com/product1/docs
example.com/product2/docs

This is exact what roots.io does with it's pages (eg: https://roots.io/bedrock/intro/ ; https://roots.io/sage/intro/)

The problem is i didn't found any solution for this aproach (using same subpages slugs for multiple parent pages).

How do they do it?

Comment: They duplicate each post and place them to their own category?

Comment: It is possible to create subpages with the same name under different parent pages. If that's the question, just pick the parent page at "Page Attributes" combo in the editor. Save it and edit the slug.